# Default server1 name change in webspher application server

Tags: websphere, websphere-9

Can we change the server name which is by default server1 is set but now we want to change because 2 profiles there both server name server1 so any steps there for name change webspher application server 9 in Linux

Comment: You can have many profiles with `server1` as a server name, as they are in different profiles and have different ports. What is the actual issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to change the server name.
However when you create the profile you can provide the server name, just select **Advanced profile creation** if you use GUI, or specify it as a parameter if you use `manageprofile` tool - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=mpdios-manageprofiles-command